# how to select duplicated column value in sql

Tags: sql

Write a query that determines the customer that has spent the most on music for each country. Write a query that returns the country along with the top customer and how much they spent. For countries where the top amount spent is shared, provide all customers who spent this amount.

You should only need to use the Customer and Invoice tables.

i want to select the customer with the maximum money spent for each country and there is two customers have the same money spent and the same country so when using group by country i got only 1 customer what should i do ?

```
select c.CustomerId,c.FirstName,c.LastName, c.Country , max(c.Invoices) as TotalSpent 
from
   (select * , sum(i.Total) as 'Invoices'
   from Customer d
   join Invoice i on i.CustomerId = d.CustomerId
   group by i.CustomerId
) c  
group by c.Country
```

the table i got is the same expected table except 1 customer

[image]

[image]

Comment: What database are you using since both your aggregate queries are not valid SQL due to incomplete `GROUP BY`?

Comment: this IDE on Udacity

Comment: We wonder which DBMS (and which version) you are using. Please try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`. If you are using MySQL or MariaSQL, you'll probably get this information and can tell us then.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query is almost correct. It should be

```
select d.*, sum(i.Total) as Invoices
from Customer d
join Invoice i on i.CustomerId = d.CustomerId
group by d.CustomerId
```

It is allowed to use `d.*` here, as we can assume `d.CustomerId` to be the table's primary key, so all columns in the table are functionally dependent on it. If we grouped by `d.country` instead for instance, that would not be the case and `d.*` would be forbidden in the select clause (as well as `d.firstname` etc.). We can only select columns we grouped by (directly or indirectly) and aggregates such as `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM` etc.

This query gives you the totals per customer along with the customers' countries.

But then you are taking this result and group by `country`. If you do this, you can only access `country` and its aggregates. Selecting `c.CustomerId` for instance is invalid, as there is no ***the*** customer ID per country. If your DBMS allows this, it it flawed in this regard and you get a kind of random result.

If your DBMS features window functions, you can get the maximum amounts per country on-the-fly:

```
select customerid, firstname, lastname, country, invoices
from
(
  select
    c.*,
    sum(i.total) as invoices,
    max(sum(i.total)) over (partition by c.country) as max_sum
  from customer c
  join invoice i on i.customerid = c.customerid
  group by c.customerid
) per_customer
where invoices = max_sum
order by country, customerid;
```

Otherwise you'd have to use your inner query twice, once to get the country totals, once to get the customers matching these totals:

```
select 
  c.customerid, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.country,
  sum(i.total) as invoices
from customer c
join invoice i on i.customerid = c.customerid
group by c.customerid
having (c.country, invoices) in
(
  select country, max(invoices)
  from
  (
    select
      --c.customerid, <- optional, it may make this query more readable
      c.country,
      sum(i.total) as invoices
    from customer c
    join invoice i on i.customerid = c.customerid
    group by c.customerid
  ) per_customer
);
```

Comment: it didn't work this ide didn't support partition by   .... thanks for help

Comment: It's probably the DBMS, not the IDE not featuring this. Then use your inner query twice, as mentioned. Have you tried that? Well, I've added such query to my answer. Anyway, maybe the window/partition clause was not even the problem. I just noticed that I missed a table alias in my query, which is required by most DBMS. I've added it. (I named it `per_customer`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining unit level with two aggregate queries: 1) first to calculate total amount by *CustomerId* and *Country* and 2) second to calculate max total amount by *Country*.

Below assumes your database supports Common Table Expression (CTE) using the `WITH` clause (nearly supported by all major commercial or open-source RDBMS's). CTE here avoids the need to repeat *sum_agg* as a subquery.

```
with sum_agg AS (
    select i.CustomerId, sub_c.Country, sum(i.Total) as Sum_Amount
    from Customer sub_c
    join Invoice i on i.CustomerId = sub_c.CustomerId
    group by i.CustomerId, sub_c.Country     
)

select c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Country, max_agg.Max_Sum
from Customer c
join sum_agg
   on c.CustomerId = sum_agg.Customer_Id and c.Country = sum_agg.Country 
join 
   (select Country, max(Sum_Amount) as Max_Sum
    from sum_agg
    group by Country
   ) max_agg
   on max_agg.Country = sum_agg.Country and max_agg.Max_Sum = sum_agg.Sum_Amount
```